# How do I disable automatic slash appending

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If my link is `example.com/page/1` it will correct to `example.com/page/1/`. How do I prevent this redirect from happening? Do I need to change something in my .htaccess or do I have to edit the server config file?

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Options All -Indexes
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some .htaccess rules in place. Can you post the relevant parts in the question as well so that folks can possibly correct what's gone wrong in them?

Comment: Yes you have to write in `.htaccess`

Comment: .htaccess added. I just need to change where it states in the url "example.com/a/" to "example.com/a" any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

Comment: Hey Aditya Joshi. OP says that this redirect happens automatically, and want to prevent it, not add the slash to every url. Besides this, a good answer is usually accompanied by some introductory/explaining text. If you use the `{}` button above the edit/post field while having code selected, you'll see that it indents it with 4 spaces. This will cause the code to render as code instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is likely caused by the `DirectorySlash` directive of mod_dir. It is turned on by default. Add `DirectorySlash Off` at the beginning of your .htaccess file. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash))

If you have access to your server config file, I recommend moving everything from your .htaccess file to your server config file, then disable your .htaccess file by changing `AllowOverride` in various places in your config file to `None`.